# Should the properties inside defaultState be null or ''

Tags: reactjs, redux

Most of the tutorials online show that the properties inside initialState should be '' (if it is a string), like:

```
let defaultState = Immutable.fromJS({
    viewData: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        alist: []
    }
});
```

But if you than have a habit of explicitly stating what properties a certain component uses, like:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return viewData: state.someReducer.get('data');
}

someContainer.propTypes = {
    data: ImmutablePropTypes.mapContains({
        id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        aList: ImmutablePropTypes.list.isRequired
    }),
};
```

Than the only way i will get "Failed propType" is if any of the properties got removed from the reducer and the `isRequired` somehow feels redundant since it will always give an empty string which is than passed on to someContainer child components.

However, if i do:

```
let defaultState = Immutable.fromJS({
    data: {
        id: null,
        name: null,
        aList: null
    }
});
```

Than i will get a failed proptype if the reducer didn't populate the state, isnt this wanted? However since i rarely see others set the props to null i feels there is a good reason not to.

Also, going with the null method nesting Maps in state gets confusing since it than even viewData should be null, but then you lose the information with not showing what data it really will get:

```
let defaultState = Immutable.fromJS({
    viewData: { // Shouldnt this be null than as well?
        id: null,
        name: null,
        hierarchies: { // and this
            one: null,
            two: null
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`null` is a perfectly acceptable form of default state - its an assignment value indicating that this particular property is without value.

There is a bigger question at play, which is totally dependent on your particular application (only you can answer if `null` makes sense), but to answer your particular question about it "being ok" - yes, it's ok.

I don't like using empty strings as default state, I find it misleading to the application. For example, my consuming components "understand" that a `null` value means a value **has yet** to be provided, whereas an empty string implies one has indeed been set, but it is simply empty (lets say, a user without a middlename - the value is ""). This allows the application deal with the current state of the app more appropriately.

Btw - its a very excellent question that isn't often explicitly explored in tutorials (as you mention).

Comment: I like your argument with - "that a null value means a value has yet to be provided, whereas an empty string implies one has indeed been set, but it is simply empty" and it makes a lot sense. But when i tried it more, i.e. to give my whole state null i ran into problems with Maps and properties inside those maps

Comment: I guess you are actually asking two questions - is it ok, and how would I approach that with immutablejs. As mentioned it does mean your application needs to understand the difference between null and empty (this is a good thing, as it should understand that difference) - there you probably need some null checks in there somewhere.

Comment: I guess i am. And i think what you say makes a whole lot of sense, but why are no tutorial makers going this way? Like, Dan abramov and tyler mccginnis who are quite big in the react/redux community.....Also see my updated code :)..

Comment: Regarding the update (disclaimer, really depends on your application :) ), I would personally just have viewdata as null - unless it makes sense to represent the structure when it hasn't been populated (but if that is the case, there is a good chance you are mixing structure/schema with data). If it were a "person" object, that had a child object representing "pets", if the persons name and age was null (ie not set), then it makes little sense to have pets as an empty object/array (just an example).

Comment: Regarding @dan-abramov and others - the tutorials are most likely abstract examples to explain an idea in a clear way, and the concepts you are dealing with are very application specific. So (guessing) for the sake of clarity and approachability of the learning resources they are most likely opting for brevity

Comment: Yes, i think it would be best for my application with what you have said, and as i said it makes much sense. I guess i will do a huge refractor of my reducers sometime in the future. But as you said, i noticed i would have to do a lot of null check. I tried removing the connection to the API (if that would happen sometime) and added null to some reducers state and .... (yep many null checks needed indeed). 

I guess making the viewData null and than using ImmutablePropTypes.mapContains({ in the components will be enough to show the information flow.

Comment: Although i think explicitly stating the data a certain reducer will receive makes it easier to understand the code and also acts as a filter layer.

Comment: It's really a tricky to call to make from the outside (from my perspective), initially I wanted to answer your base question (is it ok) and we have kind of gone deeper - which is a good thing. It's probably also worth striking up a conversation in one of the react forums / reddit/r/reactjs to get an answer to the more subjective part of your question